# How to check if a contact belongs to a campaign in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two models Campaign and Contact:

```
class Campaign extends Model {

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'campaign_contacts');
    }
}

class Contact extends Model {

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'gender', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'company', 'position', 'website_url', 'facebook_url', 'twitter_url', 'instagram_url', 'misc_url1', 'misc_url2', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'citytown', 'postcode', 'country_id', 'work_email', 'home_email', 'work_phone', 'mobile_phone', 'home_phone', 'general_notes', 'latitude', 'longitude'];

    // relationship to categories
    public function campaigns()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Campaign', 'campaign_contacts');
    }
}
```

So a contact can belong to many campaigns and a campaign can have many contacts. If I have a campaign ID how can I retrieve all contacts that don't belong to that campaign ID. I've been looking at scopes and that looks like it might be the way to go but I'm not sure what logic would go in the scope if this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (You already have a campaign_id in `$campaignId` variable):

```
$contacts = Contact::whereHas('campaigns', function($query) use ($campaignId) {
    $query->where('campaign_id', '!=', $campaignId)->orWhereNull('campaign_id');
})->get();
```